# mvn test fails, but tests pass if run per package

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, junit

I have a project with the following structure

```
src
  |_ main
  |   |_ java
  |       |_ com.company.product
  |           |_ packageA
  |           |_ packageB
  |_ test
      |_ java
          |_ com.company.product
              |_ packageA
              |_ packageB
```

When running `mvn test`, my tests in packageA pass and the tests in packageB fail.  When running `mvn test -Dtest="com.company.product.packageB.**"`, the tests in packageB pass.  Furthermore, running  `mvn test -Dtest="com.company.product.**"` also fails the packageB tests but not the packageA tests. **Why does `mvn test` not pass all tests that should pass?**

Details on tests in packageB:

```
@Test
void createNew() {
    String user = "testUser";

    //This calls a third party API that is throwing a 
    //InvocationTargetException when running packages together
    Connection connect = new Connection(user);
    String resultText = connect.getResultText();

    assertNotNUll(connect);
    assert (resultText).equals("Process Complete");
}
```

The jar required for running the third party API call is included in the pom as follows.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.third.party.api</groupId>
        <artifactId>third-party-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Using Java 1.8.0_74 and Maven 3.5.4.

**EDIT:** Error returned by Maven:

```
createNew()  Time elapsed: 0.001 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at com.company.product.packageB.MyTest.createNew(MyTest.java:11)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at com.company.product.packageB.MyTest.createNew(MyTest.java:11)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error when creating RpcClientStub. Cause : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not i
nitialize class com.third.party.apitransport.session.ArRpcCallContext
        at com.company.product.packageB.MyTest.createNew(MyTest.java:11)
```

...

```
Results :

Tests in error:
  MyTest.createNew:11 » Runtime java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetEx...
  MyTest.createAndUpdate:29 » Runtime java.lang.reflect.Invocation...
  MyTest.connect:51 » Runtime java.lang.reflect.InvocationTarget...

Tests run: 9, Failures: 0, Errors: 3, Skipped: 0
```

**EDIT:** The fix was to add cleanup as Ivan pointed out in the comments.

```
private static String systemOsName;
@BeforeAll
public static void setOsName(){
    systemOsName = System.getProperty("os.name");
}
...
@AfterAll
public static void cleanup(){
    Constants.setFilePathSeparator("");
    System.setProperty("os.name",systemOsName);
}
```

Comment: You should post the full error returned by Maven.

Comment: Presumably they're contending for some shared resource.

Comment: I have 3 tests in MyTest.java, and running all 3 together passes.  Do you mean the packages are contending for a shared resource?  PackageA does not use the third party api that is at the line throwing the error, for reference.

Comment: Looks like tests in `packageA` do not perform clean up (close resources/connections, delete files created, rollback database changes) after they are done. Because of that tests in `packageB` cannot initialize those resources

Comment: Not sure what resources would need to be cleaned up.  The packageA tests are very basic.  The following is about as complex as they get:
https://gist.github.com/JohnSBarden/1475872f2feb4133c7d1e9d544e4f1f8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are multiple tests that are setting the `System.setProperty("os.name", "windows")` value, then this will need to be reset at the end with a cleanup if that value is used to determine a value later in your package b tests.